# Drop position problem when dragging DIV onto Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

The javascript below allows me to drag a DIV onto a canvas. I am loading a multi-page PDF (actually image files) in a popup window and placing canvas layers over them and loading shapes in each canvas at certain coordinates.

The code below is mostly working except for when the div is "dropped" onto the canvas, it does not drop where the cursor is. The div drops up and to the right of wherever my cursor is on the canvas.

The page width (918) and height (1188) are static and never change.

I'm assuming this has something to do with the div's offset as it's relative to the page's offset but I cannot seem to get it right.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
$('.canvas-container').each(function (index, item) {
var canvasContainer = $(this)[index];
var canvasObject = $("canvas", this)[index];

var divOffsetX, divOffsetY;

var sigDivs = $(".sigFields").last();
divOffsetX = sigDivs.offset().left;
divOffsetY = sigDivs.offset().top;

function handleDragOver(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
    return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
    this.classList.add('over');
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
    this.classList.remove('over');
}

function handleDrop(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    var div = document.querySelector('.sigFields div.div_dragging');
    console.log('event: ', e);

    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var y = e.clientY - (offset.top + divOffsetY);
    var x = e.clientX - (offset.left + divOffsetX);


    var newSigDiv = new fabric.Rect({
        width: 234,
        height: 24,
        left: x,
        top: y,
        lockRotation: true,
        hasRotatingPoint: false
    });

    fabricCanvas.add(newSigDiv);
    return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
    [].forEach.call(divs, function (div) {
        div.classList.remove('div_dragging');
    });
}

var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.sigFields div');
[].forEach.call(divs, function (div) {
    div.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
    div.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
});

canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
canvasContainer.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
```

});

Answer (score 1):

The fix was simple.

Rather than attempt some weird math with the offsets, I changed

left: x,
left: y

to

left: e.layerX,
top: e.layerY